# How to append array of nested objects using Formik with file upload

Tags: reactjs, formik

I'm trying to make a dynamic form where if the user wants to add an additional section to their pages. For instance, if they want to add a "Our Team" section, I'm trying to render an array of nested objects, but I'm kinda confuse since each team member can have image as well.

My backend works when I try on Postman. I'm using multer and Schema looks like this:

```
const sectionSchema = new Schema({
  team: [
    {
      name: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
      },
      jobTitle: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
      },
      description: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
      },
      images: [
        {
          filename: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
          },
          contentType: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
          },
          imageBase64: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  ]
});
```

Problem is when I submit says that:

```
Warning: An unhandled error was caught from submitForm() TypeError: item.images.forEach is not a function
    at BaseFormAditional.js:80:1
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at submitHandler (BaseFormAditional.js:75:1)
    at onSubmit (BaseFormAditional.js:123:1)
    at Formik.tsx:849:1
    at Formik.tsx:1200:1
    at Formik.tsx:756:1
```

Somehow, it does not matter how I handle images, it does not see as an array.

**BaseFormAditional.js**

```
const BaseFormAditional = () => {

  const initialValues = {

    // Team section
    teamTitle: "",
    team: [
      {
        name: "",
        jobTitle: "",
        description: "",
        images: [],
      },
    ]
  };

  const pageId = useParams().pageId;
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const submitHandler = async (values) => {
    const formData = new FormData();

    values.team.forEach((item, index) => {
      formData.append(`team[${index}][name]`, item.name);
      formData.append(`team[${index}][jobTitle]`, item.jobTitle);
      formData.append(`team[${index}][description]`, item.description);
    
      item.images.forEach((image, imageIndex) => {
        formData.append(`team[${index}][images][${imageIndex}][filename]`, image.filename);
        formData.append(`team[${index}][images][${imageIndex}][contentType]`, image.contentType);
        formData.append(`team[${index}][images][${imageIndex}][imageBase64]`, image.imageBase64);
      });
    });


    formData.append("pageId", pageId);

    // later axios as formData
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Formik
        initialValues={initialValues}
        onSubmit={(values) => submitHandler(values)}
      >
        {({ values, setFieldValue }) => (
          <Form>
            {/* TEAM SECTION */}
            <div>
              {showTeamForm && (
                <div>
                  <h1>Team</h1>
                  <label htmlFor="contact-title">Team Title:</label>
                  <br />
                  <Field id="team-title" name="teamTitle" />

                  <FieldArray name="team">
                    {({ insert, remove, push }) => (
                      <div>
                        {values.team.length > 0 &&
                          values.team.map((friend, index) => (
                            <div className="row" key={index}>
                              <div className="col">
                                <label htmlFor={`team.${index}.name`}>
                                  Name
                                </label>
                                <Field
                                  name={`team.${index}.name`}
                                  placeholder="Jane Doe"
                                  type="text"
                                />
                                <ErrorMessage
                                  name={`team.${index}.name`}
                                  component="div"
                                  className="field-error"
                                />
                              </div>

                              <div className="col">
                                <label htmlFor={`team.${index}.jobTitle`}>
                                  Phone number
                                </label>
                                <Field
                                  name={`team.${index}.jobTitle`}
                                  placeholder="Marketing"
                                  type="text"
                                />
                                <ErrorMessage
                                  name={`team.${index}.jobTitle`}
                                  component="div"
                                  className="field-error"
                                />
                              </div>

                              <div className="col">
                                <label htmlFor={`team.${index}.description`}>
                                  Description
                                </label>
                                <Field
                                  name={`team.${index}.description`}
                                  placeholder="About team member"
                                  type="text"
                                />
                                <ErrorMessage
                                  name={`team.${index}.description`}
                                  component="div"
                                  className="field-error"
                                />
                              </div>

                              <div className="col">
                                <label htmlFor={`team.${index}.images`}>
                                  Upload image
                                </label>
                                <FileInput
                                  name={`team.${index}.images`}
                                  type="file"
                                  value={undefined}
                                />
                                {/* <Field
                                  name={`team.${index}.images`}
                                  type="file"
                                /> */}
                                <ErrorMessage
                                  name={`team.${index}.images`}
                                  component="div"
                                  className="field-error"
                                />
                              </div>

                              <div className="col">
                                <button
                                  type="button"
                                  className="secondary"
                                  onClick={() => remove(index)}
                                >
                                  Delete Member
                                </button>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          ))}
                        <button
                          type="button"
                          className="secondary"
                          onClick={() =>
                            push({
                              name: "",
                              jobTitle: "",
                              description: "",
                              images: "",
                            })
                          }
                        >
                          Add Member
                        </button>
                      </div>
                    )}
                  </FieldArray>
                </div>
              )}
            </div>

            <div>
              <button type="submit">Save</button>
            </div>
          </Form>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
};

export default BaseFormAditional;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is on setting type images form and read this property.

As you can see. When you submit the form, you are setting images as a string or a single file, not as an array.

```js
<div className="col">
    <label htmlFor={`team.${index}.images`}>
        Upload image
    </label>
    <FileInput
        name={`team.${index}.images`}
        type="file"
        value={undefined}
    />
    {/* <Field name={`team.${index}.images`} type="file"/> */}
    <ErrorMessage
        name={`team.${index}.images`}
        component="div"
        className="field-error"
    />
</div>

...
<button
    type="button"
    className="secondary"
    onClick={() =>
       push({
           name: "",
           jobTitle: "",
           description: "",
           // images: "", Specify an array
           images: []
       })
    }
>
    Add Member
</button>
```

If you check `team[0].images` on submit, you will check that `team[0].images` is a file, not an array.

If you want to save image in the array, you need to specify index position when you want to save it.

```js
<div className="col">
    <label htmlFor={`team.${index}.images[0]`}>
        Upload image
    </label>
    <FileInput
        name={`team.${index}.images[0]`}
        type="file"
        value={undefined}
    />
    {/* <Field name={`team.${index}.images[0]`} type="file"/> */}
    <ErrorMessage
        name={`team.${index}.images[0]`}
        component="div"
        className="field-error"
    />
</div>
```

Furthermore, if your objective is creating dynamic input files, you must to add another fieldArray to manage this property.

```js
// upgrade above code
<FieldArray name={`team.${index}.images`}>
    // not destructure, otherwise conflict with push, remove from FieldArray parent
    {(fileHelpers) => (
       { team[index].images.map( (image, indexFile) =>
         <div className="col">
             <label htmlFor={`team.${index}.images`}>
                 Upload image
             </label>
             <FileInput
                 name={`team.${index}.images[0]`}
                 type="file"
                 value={undefined}
             />
             {/* <Field name={`team.${index}.images[0]`} type="file"/> */}
                 <ErrorMessage
                 name={`team.${index}.images[0]`}
                 component="div"
                 className="field-error"
             />
             // Add button to push another element to array
             <button
                 type="button"
                 className="secondary"
                 onClick={() =>
                     fileHelpers.push({})
                 }
              >
                  Add File
              </button>
         </div>
       }
    )}
</FieldArray>
```